# Npgsql 3.2.0 is not compatible with 'Npgsql.EntityFramework 2.2.7 constraint: Npgsql (= 2.2.7)'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

During EF migration, Update-Database step is causing problem.

I have added a new table to my existing schema by adding a model class and its dbset declaration in context class. Then i did "Add-Migration xxxx" which works fine. But "Update-Database" results in some strange npgsql version(my guess) which I had never seen before.

The error I get in Package Manager Console is:

```cs
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException,Npgsql, Version=2.2.4.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'.
at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Type is not resolved for member 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException,Npgsql, Version=2.2.4.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'.
```

So I upgraded my Npgsql to a version above 3.0.1 based on the answer in link: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/714

Upgrading that fails by complaining that,

```cs
 Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Npgsql 3.2.0' is not compatible with 'Npgsql.EntityFramework 2.2.7 constraint: Npgsql (= 2.2.7)'.
```

But my project is using Npgsql.EntityFramework 2.2.5 everywhere and not 2.2.7.

So I tried upgrading Npgsql.EntityFramework to different versions but none of the trial-and-error version lets me upgrade Npgsql to 3.0.1 and above at all.

Update-Database should just work fine and update the underlying schema with newly added table. Let me know if i am doing something wrong or missing something obvious.

Comment: Open the .proj file with a notepad and check versions.

Comment: that has the versions as shown above.

Comment: If you want a different version then edit the .proj file.  It got updated automatically. Make sure you still have older version on machine.

Comment: Nope. Its not helping. its causing some other errors.

Comment: You may have to do a clean build.  Can you compare the original project file that was working to the latest?